# Delete elements appearing before one element and itself

Tags: r, list

I have a list of elements (letter here in the example)

```
 (l <- list(letters[1:2], letters[2:3]))

# [[1]]    
# [1] "a" "b"    
# [[2]]   
# [1] "b" "c" 

 And another elements 
(r <- letters[2])

# [1] "b"
```

The R function must delete  evrything before "b" and "b" itself.

So the result will be like this :

```
 # [[1]]    
 # [1] "c"
```

Any idea please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
out = lapply(l, function(x) x[-c(1,which(x == "b"))])
Filter(length, out)

#[[1]]
#[1] "c"
```

or as @akrun suggested

```
Filter(length,lapply(l, function(x) x[-seq(match("b",x))]))
```

Comment: Or use `match` `Filter(length,lapply(l, function(x) x[-seq(match(r,x))]))`

Comment: It works @Veerendra Gadekar thank you very much!! Cheers